# VSIX: IErrorTag tooltip content not displaying

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, mef, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I am trying to write a code analysis extension for visual studio using MEF. I have implemented the `ITagger` interface for an `IErrorTag` along with the required `ITaggerProvider`. As a result, i get the expected squiggles in the editor window for the issues my code analysis finds. However, when hovering above the squiggles with the mouse, the respective tooltip content is never displayed.

Here is a minimalistic example which has the same problem:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Adornments;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CodeAnalyzer
{
  struct DummyIssue
  {
    public int Line; // one based line
    public string ToolTip;

    public DummyIssue(int line, string toolTip)
    {
      Line = line;
      ToolTip = toolTip;
    }
  }

  internal class DummyCodeCheckTagger : ITagger<IErrorTag>
  {
    readonly List<DummyIssue> mIssues;
    readonly ITextView TextView;

    public DummyCodeCheckTagger(ITextView textView)
    {
      TextView = textView;
      mIssues = new List<DummyIssue>
      {
        new DummyIssue(1, "asldfjoqwet"),
        new DummyIssue(7, "ASASDAER")
      };

      textView.LayoutChanged += Update;
    }

    public event EventHandler<SnapshotSpanEventArgs> TagsChanged;

    private void Update(object sender, TextViewLayoutChangedEventArgs args)
    {
      TagsChanged?.Invoke(this, new SnapshotSpanEventArgs(new SnapshotSpan(args.NewSnapshot, 0, args.NewSnapshot.Length)));
    }

    IEnumerable<ITagSpan<IErrorTag>> ITagger<IErrorTag>.GetTags(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans)
    {
      var issues = mIssues;
      foreach (var span in spans)
      {
        foreach (var issue in issues)
        {
          int zeroBasedLine = issue.Line - 1;
          ITextSnapshotLine snapshotLine = TextView.TextSnapshot.GetLineFromLineNumber(zeroBasedLine);
          SnapshotSpan snapshotSpan = snapshotLine.Extent;
          if (spans.IntersectsWith(snapshotSpan))
          {
            yield return new TagSpan<IErrorTag>(snapshotSpan, new ErrorTag(PredefinedErrorTypeNames.SyntaxError, issue.ToolTip));
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result looks like this:
[tooltip not displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QMnD.png)

What am i missing to get the tooltip displayed?

Comment: Try to refer to [this document](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/157b3f6d-eadd-4693-b8f2-458f837b4394/mef-errortag-how-to-get-the-errortag-tooltipcontent-to-work-in-vs2010-extensibility-component?forum=vsx).

Comment: Thanks fater, I already tried that one but it did not help in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fater's comment above led me to think about the problem again. Since i already tried the suggestions in the [document](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/157b3f6d-eadd-4693-b8f2-458f837b4394/mef-errortag-how-to-get-the-errortag-tooltipcontent-to-work-in-vs2010-extensibility-component?forum=vsx) posted by fater without success, i started thinking if the problem could be somewhere else.

It turns out that the `ITagger` implementation was not the problem, but the `ITaggerProvider` implementation caused the strange behavior. For that,
I pretty much followed the [VSIX ErrorList](https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/ErrorList) example implementing a SpellChecker, which contains the following code

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Create a tagger that does spell checking on the view/buffer combination.
        /// </summary>
        public ITagger<T> CreateTagger<T>(ITextView textView, ITextBuffer buffer) where T : ITag
        {
            ITagger<T> tagger = null;

            // Only attempt to spell check on the view's edit buffer (and multiple views could have that buffer open simultaneously so
            // only create one instance of the spell checker.
            if ((buffer == textView.TextBuffer) && (typeof(T) == typeof(IErrorTag)))
            {
                var spellChecker = buffer.Properties.GetOrCreateSingletonProperty(typeof(SpellChecker), () => new SpellChecker(this, textView, buffer));

                // This is a thin wrapper around the SpellChecker that can be disposed of without shutting down the SpellChecker
                // (unless it was the last tagger on the spell checker).
                tagger = new SpellCheckerTagger(spellChecker) as ITagger<T>;
            }

            return tagger;
        }
```

The point is, that the code above only creates an `ITagger` for a certain view. In that case the created tagger is used only for providing the squiggles in the editor window view. Visual Studio uses a different tagger instance for providing the tooltips for the squiggles and another tagger instance for coloring the scroll bar in the editor window. I had assumed that this would be done by one single tagger instance.